# TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface and it's not all

Tags: python-3.x

```
`import socket
def Main():
    host = "127.0.0.1"
    port = 2000

    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((host, port))

    message = input("-> ")

    while message != "q":
        s.send(message)
        data = s.recv(1024)
        print("Received from server: " + str(data))
        message = input("-> ") 
    s.close()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Main() #a problem with this code`
```

errors are given here(http://pastebin.com/AvaGSJzB)
please, help me
i don't know what to do

Comment: Please put your errors in full here, together with how you invoke this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error means that you are trying to pass a Unicode string to a interface that expects binary data such as `bytes`, `bytearray`:

```
encoding = 'utf-8'
s.send(message.encode(encoding))
data = s.recv(1024).decode(encoding) # assume the whole answer arrived
```

Or you could wrap the socket object in a text file using `s.makefile()`, to avoid encoding the text manually.

Comment: Thanks, could you help me with this file too? (http://pastebin.com/GSckEaz7)

Comment: It's the same story...

Comment: @DanielPastushchak: don't put the code in pastebin, [update your question instead](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/25704570/edit). You've copied the code incorrectly.

Comment: This can also happen if you are using Python 3.3